# bs4 library works in terminal but cant find parser in pycharm

Tags: beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, pycharm

I'm trying to run my python file in Pycharm but it gives the following error. When I try to, it gives this error. However it runs fine in the terminal without errors.

```
  File "/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/python/asx options updator/main.py", line 43, in fetch_html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/python/asx options updator/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    test()
  File "/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/python/asx options updator/main.py", line 53, in test
    fetch_html(link)
  File "/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/python/asx options updator/main.py", line 43, in fetch_html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

I have tried

```
pip3 install lxml
pip install lxml
```

lxml is also included in the project interpreter.
[image]

Edit1:
After running this [script](https://lxml.de/elementsoup.html#using-soupparser-as-a-fallback)  to test lxml, Pycharm gave me the following error while it ran fine in terminal.

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 "/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/python/asx options updator/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/python/asx options updator/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.py)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/python/asx options updator/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Is `lxml` along working for you? Can you run this dummy script: https://lxml.de/elementsoup.html#using-soupparser-as-a-fallback

Comment: it gives the following error while running in pycharm


`
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.py)
`



while it runs monstly fine in terminal except for tostring not being defined

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you select or start Pycharm in the correct environment? Obviously it can't find `lxml` and hence can't be used as bs4 parser.

Comment: Ok yeah, you were right. I had no idea that pycharm was using my python 3.7 interpreters in user/bin instead of the python 3 folders used in the terminal. Now that I have added a new environment from python 3 its working fine now.  Though I still have lots of different python versions in user/bin. Are so many versions going to be a problem later on?